# Style all date formats in a string in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, text

I have an excel spreadsheet and within one column there are various comments for the specific entry (row).
Each time a user adds a new comment, the current date ("dd.mm.yyyy") is added before the new comment.
The following example represents one cell with various comments:

```
29.03.2019: newest comment
28.03.2019: an older comment
25.02.2019: more test
maybe with line break
12.12.2018: the first comment
```

What I'm looking for is a way to detect all parts in the cell's value (string) which represent a date (formatted like dd.mm.yyy) and set the font style to bold.

So it should look like:

**29.03.2019**: newest comment

**28.03.2019**: an older comment

**25.02.2019**: more test

maybe with line break

**12.12.2018**: the first comment

Answer (score 1):

This one should do but it's a bit of an overkill, especially if your range is big

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Position As Integer
Dim FontRange As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set FontRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A100") ' set your range with comments

For Each cell In FontRange
    Position = InStr(cell.Value, ":")
    If Position > 0 Then
    With cell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=Position).Font
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
    End With
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this works but only for the first date in a cell and also makes text bold when it is not a date